# Generate arbitrarily nested tuples in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have an input relation `X` that looks like this:

```
a:chararray, b:chararray, c:(d:chararray, e:(f:chararray, g:chararray))
```

I'd like to generate that *exact* tuple again, syntactically, in a single generate statement. This doesn't work, but hopefully it gives a good example of what I'm after:

```
foreach x generate a as a, b as b, (d as d, (f as f, g as g) as e) as c
```

In reality, I'm generating code to make small edits to the type, so an answer like:

```
foreach x generate *
```

...isn't useful here.

Is there a syntax that will let me generate arbitrarily nested structures like this in a single generate statement in Pig? It's fair to assume a fully `FLATTEN`-ed type -- that is, arbitrarily nested tuples without bags, maps, etc.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:** I've gotten a little closer. This *almost* works:

```
x = LOAD 'data.json' USING JsonLoader('a:chararray, b:chararray') AS a:chararray, b:chararray;
y = foreach x generate (a, b, (a, b, (a, b))) as (a:chararray, b:chararray, tuple1:(a:chararray, b:chararray, tuple2:(a:chararray, b:chararray)));
```

Semantically, this is The Right Thing and it's syntactically valid, but it gives me this error:

```
Incompatable schema: left is "a:chararray,b:chararray,tuple1:tuple(a:chararray,b:chararray,tuple2:tuple(a:chararray,b:chararray))", right is "org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_b_3:tuple(a:chararray,b:chararray,org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_b_2:tuple(a:chararray,b:chararray,org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_b_1:tuple(a:chararray,b:chararray)))"
```

...which seems strange to me, because either (a) the two schemas should match, or (b) there is an additional tuple "layer" on the right which is syntactically impossible to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be

```
y = foreach x generate a,b,
    TOTUPLE(c.d,TOTUPLE(c.e.f,c.e.g)) 
         as c:(d:chararray,e:(f:chararray,g:chararray));
```

Comment: Thank you! The `TOTUPLE` function is what I was missing!